# Turn encoded ASCII strings into raw characters to store in a MySQL table

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I need to turn multiple strings, e.g. `=E2=86=92` into raw characters in PHP. These strings come from the body of emails retrieved via IMAP.

Comment: Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Straight from my mail server. imap_body

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that one-sentence questions with no evidence of prior effort usually get downvoted here. You won't always get a high-quality answer in seven minutes, so if you can show us what you have tried, it helps both you and your readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extract the individual sequences representing a single byte, and convert the hex number to a byte.

A regular expression can be used to extract the =XX sequences, the [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/hexdec) function can convert a hex string sequence to an integer, and the [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) function can convert an integer to a byte.

```
$inputString = '=E2=86=92';

$binaryString = preg_replace_callback('/=[A-F0-9]{2}/', function($match) {
    return chr(hexdec($match[0]));
}, $inputString);
```

http://3v4l.org/4MWiq

Comment: exactly the answer I was looking for, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is not fully correct. MIME encodings, even as simple as quoted-printable, are full of traps and pitfalls that require a lot of work to be handled correctly. This solution, for example, doesn't implement RFC 2045, section 6-5, p. 5 (soft line breaks). Do yourself a favor, don't reinvent wheels, use a dedicated function (not to mention that it's going to be ~100 times faster).

Comment: @georg agreed, but the question does not specify any of those things. I'm sure there is a better solution to the specific problem domain, but since I don't actually know what the specific problem domain is I cannot offer it. This fully satisfies the original specifications, but I'm quite happy to concede that it's not the best possible answer to the question, it is only *an* answer to the question *as it stands*.